# Prawn text_box border

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I'm using Prawn 2-0.2.4 to make pdf over Rails 3.1 application. I'm a great issue; I'm not able to see text_box border; this  is my action:

```
def firma_conducente
  text_box "Firma Conducente ________  Firma Cessionario _____", :rotate => 270, :size => 10, :at=> [500,500], :width => 600, :height => 1200 do
    stroke_color = 'FFFF00'
  end
end
```

I can see text inside pdf generated file but I don't know how can I see border too.
Moreover, is there a way to put this text_box on each document's page?

Answer (score 8):

You can draw a bounding box around it and place the following commands in it:

```
stroke_color 'FFFF00'
stroke_bounds
```

for example like this

```
Prawn::Document.generate 'example.pdf' do
  bounding_box([0,750], :width => 550, :height => 750) do
    stroke_color 'FFFF00'
    stroke_bounds
    text_box "Firma Conducente ________  Firma Cessionario _____", 
          :size => 10, :at=> [50,700], :width => 550, :height => 750 
  end
end
```

Comment: Since there is now some padding between the bounding_box and the text_box, you would probably want to reduce the width and height of the text_box accordingly.

Comment: hey, +1 for the answer. One clarification - how can I format (bold, underline) the pdf.draw_text inside the bounding_box? thanks!

Comment: What if I don't know height, because it's different for different translations?